# Remove selected items Listview

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm tring to remove the selected items in a ListView, so i wrote this code.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if(requestCode == 1) {
        try {
            for(int a=0; a<myAdapter.getCustomItemPositions().size(); a++) {
                applicationInfo = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(myAdapter.getArrayListPosition().get(a), a);
            }
        } catch(PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            applicationInfoArrayList.remove(myAdapter.getCustomItemPositions());
            Log.d("Example", "removed items at positions "+myAdapter.getCustomItemPositions());
            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

    }
    else {

    }
}
```

In the Logcat i see this:

"Removed items at positions [10,11]
 Removed items at positions [10,11] "

The main problem is that although the log is correct positions of the elements to be removed, however, remain on the list. Why? Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the item directly from the adapter:

```
adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(position));
```